# Getting parameters from applicationManager

Tags: webos, enyo

I am basically executing the following luna-send command and trying to get those parameters from applicationManager:

```
luna-send -n 1 palm://com.palm.power/timeout/set '{"wakeup":true, "key":"myKey",
"uri":"palm://com.palm.applicationManager/launch","params":{"id":"com.my.app", 
"params":{"test":true,"test1:true}},"in":"00:00:15"}'
```

After executing this command, my app gets launched by applicationManager, but I don't know how to get those params in my app. I am using enyo 2.0. I was trying to use onWindowsParamsChange handler, but ApplicationEvents is deprecated for 2.0. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Enyo 1.0 it was `enyo.windowParams`.  Under Enyo 2.0 I believe this functionality is gone.  These parameters may be available through Cordova, but I'm not positive right now as I don't have the source handy. In any case, this was loaded from `PalmSystem.launchParams` so you should be able to access that.

If you're handling relaunch then you'll have a little more work to do.  I think you'll need to define a `Mojo.relaunch` on the window object to detect when the launch parameters change.

Comment: Thanks! PalmSystem.launchParams works for me :) I have one more question though regarding app being relaunched. Could you give me some code snippet for detecting the app relaunching from the card view?

Comment: Do you mean a relaunch or just coming out of card view?

Comment: Isn't relaunching the app the same as getting out of card view and going back to the full screen mode?

Comment: Not at all.  The events for carding are Activated and Deactivated.  Check Enyo 1.0 source: source/palm/system/windows/events.js